# integral w.r.t. Brownian motion is gaussian process?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Consider the stochastic term from the solution of the SDE of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process:

$$X_t=\sigma \int_0^te^{-\lambda(t-s)} \, dBs, $$ where $\sigma>0$.

How can be seen that $X_t$ is a Gaussian process?

Comment: BTW this is called a Wiener integral (when the integrand is deterministic).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write out the Riemann sums which converge to the stochastic integral defining $X_t$, each is a linear combination of the jointly Gaussian random variables $B_{s_i}$ for some finitely many values of $s_i$, with deterministic coefficients.  So the Riemann sum defines a Gaussian random variable.  Then the integral in $X_t$ is a limit i.p. of Gaussian random variables, which must therefore be Gaussian (this is easy to check using characteristic functions, for instance).

A similar argument would show that any linear combination $\sum a_i X_{t_i}$ is likewise Gaussian, so $X_t$ is a Gaussian process.

Comment: +1 you can even show it's a zero-mean Gaussian from the same argument